# Get the time elapsed for file created time and current time in powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

I am trying to find out whether the file in the folder existed for morethan 30 minutes or not.I need find the difference between current system time and file created time in powershell.Please help m eout

Answer (score 1):

This will return the minutes since the files had been copied.

```
 $($(Get-Date) - $(gci filename).CreationTime).Minutes
```

Comment: Please tell how to get the list of files in a folder(may contain subfolder) which are 30 min old

Comment: this line of code works for a single file, you can use it in a loop. Show a bit of effort and some code so people can help you out.

Comment: the above code will not solve my problem i have figure it out.any ways thanks for your answer and i know how to code
((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).TotalMinutes -gt $minsOld

it should be total minutes not minutes